# What bright body is next to the Moon in these photos of the ISS transiting the lunar disk?

Tags: the-moon, identify-this-object

The question [What are the chances that the ISS transits the moon as seen from your house (or headquarters)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29879/12102) links to the SpaceX Instagram-posted photos of the ISS transiting the Moon's disk as seen from SpaceX headquarters.

There's a bright object next to the Moon, but I'm not sure exactly when this happened. Instagram says "last weekend" which would appear to be the last weekend of July in 2018.

What bright object is this, next to the Moon? Planet? Star?

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bl8xjJFFrHM/

[image: ISS lunar transit Spacex] [image: ISS lunar transit Spacex]

Comment: tag recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the appearance of the moon, that must have been photographed on the weekend of the 21-22 (the moon was nearly full on the 28-29)

The object is Jupiter, and from the position I'd say the photograph was taken at about 0400 UTC on the 21st July 2018.

I think Antares can be dimmly seen towards the left of the photo, and perhaps alpha and beta Libra area visible above and below the moon, but I can't see any other stars.

Comment: Aha, possibly obvious in hindsight, but I completely missed that. Thanks!